# Is it GCC error?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

When compiling my project mixing `C` and `C++` heavily I get this error (this when compiling C++ file):

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++locale.h:
In function ‘int std::__convert_from_v(__locale_struct* const&, char*, int, const char*, ...)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++locale.h:70:3:
sorry, unimplemented:
function ‘int std::__convert_from_v(__locale_struct* const&, char*, int, const char*, ...)’
can never be inlined because it uses variable argument lists
```

And compilation ends.

But when I **manually** edit file
`/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++locale.h`
and delete the `inline` modifier before `__convert_from_v` it **WORKS**.

The function header causing problems is with `inline` originally:

```
inline int
__convert_from_v(const __c_locale& __cloc __attribute__ ((__unused__)),
                   char* __out,
                   const int __size __attribute__ ((__unused__)),
                   const char* __fmt, ...)
```

I guess function like that SHOULD NOT be marked as `inline`. Is it bug or am I doing something wrong??? [gcc 4.6.1, Ubuntu 11.10]

Comment: Are you directly including this file? Whats the full error?

Comment: It'd help if you localized the error to a small piece of code and posted it.

Comment: This is a file that is almost always  used when compiling a nontrivial C++ project. It is far from liklely that this is faulty. It is more likely that your project and/or compiler invocation is to blame. But without seeing a minimal self contained code example along with the compiler invocation used to compile it, we can't tell for sure.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Do you have any idea, which files do include it? For example?

Comment: You sure it's an error? It looks like the sort of thing that would merely be a warning.

Comment: Use g++ -H to print include stack

Comment: the "sorry, unimplemented:" portion makes me think that there may be a platform-specific define which you don't have set correctly.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error message for inline/vararg functions with my gcc 4.6.2 on fedora. http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10980 is definitely related, and includes the statement "GCC always errored out on this (previously by sorry(), now with error()).". Your problem seems to be a "sorry" message, not an "error" message. Are you using Ubuntu's out-of-the-box GCC?

Comment: @James: about everything that does i/o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is likely due to optimization settings or redefinition of `inline` that force `__convert_from_v` to be inlined. Here's a small artificial example that reproduces the error:

```
#define inline __always_inline
#include <bits/c++locale.h>

int main () {
  __locale_t loc;
  return std::__convert_from_v(loc, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Compiling with g++ 4.6.1 on Ubuntu 11.10 gives the error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++locale.h: In function ‘int std::__convert_from_v(__locale_struct* const&, char*, int, const char*, ...)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++locale.h:70:3: sorry, unimplemented: function ‘int std::__convert_from_v(__locale_struct* const&, char*, int, const char*, ...)’ can never be inlined because it uses variable argument lists
```

So check your code for redefinition of `inline` or try different optimization settings.

I think the reason this function is marked as `inline` is because it is defined in a header. Without `inline` you'd get it defined in every translation unit that includes (normally indirectly) this header.

Comment: Oooooooh... YES! We have that macro for treating `inline` as `always_inline`. Fantastic point. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

C prior to C99 doesn't have the **inline** keyword. Check your compiler configuration.

Comment: He said: "When compiling my project mixing C and C++ heavily I get this error"